# Java source file encoding with Chinese character

Tags: java, encoding

I import a Java project from Windows platform to Ubuntu.
My Ubuntu is 10.10, Gnome environment: My `LANGUAGE` is set to `en_US:en`
My terminal's character encoding is: Unicode (UTF-8)
My IDE is eclipse and text file encoding is:  GBK.

In source file, there are some Chinese constant character.

The project build successful on Windows with ant,
but on Ubuntu, I get compile error:

```
illegal character: \65533
```

I don't want to use \uxxxx format as the file is already there,

And I've tried the `-encoding` option for javac, but still can't compile.

Comment: Is it possible to change your text file encoding to utf-8 and then add `encoding UTF-8` to compiler options.

Comment: The source file is getting from svn repository, and change my environment to Ubuntu is my own decision, so I think I can't change the file encoding from GBK to UTF-8. And the same Chinese character as String is OK, but as a single character, it cause the compile error.

Comment: \65533 is the replacement character U+FFFD. In order to solve the problem, write a very simple class that reproduces the problem. Then post both the source and a hex dump. By looking at that, we'll be able to tell you the exact problem.

Comment: in my test GBK java file created on ubuntu: `char ch = '国';` `System.out.println(ch);`. If I don't use `-encoding`, then I get error message:`warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF8`, but when I use `-encoding GBK`, both javac and java is happy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies not with Ubuntu, Ubuntu's console, Javac or Eclipse but with the way you transfer the file from windows to Ubuntu. You have to store it as utf-8 *before* you copy it to Ubuntu otherwise the codepoint-information that is set in your Windows your locale is already lost.

Comment: To try this out: open Notepad2 (or equivalent), switch it to utf-8, copy-paste your code into it, store it (it will use utf-8) and copy it to Ubuntu. Now compare that file with the one you transferred earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the `encoding` option of the [`<javac>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) in your `build.xml`?

It should look like this:

```
<javac encoding="GBK" ...>
```

If you haven't specified it, then on Windows it will use the platform default encoding (which is GBK in your setup) and on Linux it will use the platform default encoding (which is UTF-8 in your setup).

Since you want the build to work on both platforms (preferably without changing the configuration of either platform), you need to specify the encoding when you compile.

Comment: I've tried this, but get error message:"warning: unmappable character for encoding GBK", the error message is for comment in java source file

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert you source codes from you windows codepage to UTF-8. Use [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) for this.

Comment: No, that's not needed, chances are that Java (and thus `javac`) support the Windows encoding and he only needs to specify it in his ant build.